# Nimzowitsch Defence - 1. e4 Nc6 2. Nf3 variation

Tags: opening, analysis

I was watching a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQofyVG4ZYY) which explains the `1. e4 Nc6 2. Nf3` line of the Nimzowitsch Defence. In that video, the presenter was talking as if after `9... Nd4`, white did not have any good move.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[StartPly "18"]

1. e4 Nc6 2. Nf3 f5 3. exf5 d5 4. Nh4 e5 5. Qh5+ g6 6. fxg6 Nf6 7. g7+ Nxh5 8. gxh8=Q Qxh4 9. Qxh7 Nd4 10. Na3
```

However, I find that `10.Na3` is a better move for white than `10. Qxc7`  which was presented in the video. It prevents both `10... Qe4+` and also `10... Nc2+`.

Please share your opinions.

Comment: After `10.Na3` Black simply plays `10...Bxa3` and wins the rook...

Comment: I'm seeing `10...Bf5` and White's in for a hard day. After `10...Bxa3` I can't find a continuation for Black after Qg8+ and then Qxd5.

Comment: Qg8+ Bf8    -+.........

Answer (score 4):

White loses if plays Na3, because Black is threatening with mate via Qe4. Black gains access to e4 with Bf5 move.

```
r1b1kb2/ppp4Q/8/3pp2n/3n3q/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1KB1R w KQq - 1 10

1. Na3 Bf5 $19 {Black is threatening with Qe4, which leads to mate or tons of material gain} 2. Bb5+ {To clear escaping square f1 for King, with tempo} (2. Qxc7?? Qe4+ 3. Kd1 Bg4 4. f3 Bxf3 5. gxf3 Qxf3 6. Ke1 Qe4 7. Kd1 Be7 {White is defenseless, Bh4 coming}) c6 3. Qxb7 Qe4+ 4. Kf1 cxb5
5. Qxa8+ Kf7 6. Qxa7+ Be7 {White has no defense}
```